# end keyword always in red (just curious)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, omnipascal

I noticed that after activating OmniPascal, all [end] keywords are now in red, no matter what theme I switch to. Is it normal, or I am being stupid and messed sth?? Thank you.

Tried switching themes, uninstalling ([end]s were back to normal) and reinstalling OmniPascal

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

VSCode native bracket pair colorization doesn't work well with `begin`/`end` delimiters.

Add this to VSCode `settings.json`:

```
"[objectpascal]": {
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
}
```